# Blind construction of planar graph with additive spanning tree count

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, planar-graphs, spanning-tree

Suppose we have two planar graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ with number of spanning tree count $P_1$ and $P_2$ respectively then there is an easy construction which gives a planar graph with spanning tree count $P_1P_2$ (introduce one additional vertex $v$ and join any one vertex in Graph $G_1$ to the vertex $v$ and any one vertex in Graph $G_2$ to the vertex $v$) and this contruction does not need to know $P_1$ and $P_2$.

> Is there a graph construction in polynomial time to get a planar graph from $G_1$ and $G_2$ with spanning tree count $P_1+P_2$ without knowing $P_1$ or $P_2$ when $P_1+P_2>2$ holds?

Comment: There is no simple graph (planar or otherwise) with exactly 2 spanning trees, right?

Comment: Well, you get every number greater than 2  by considering the cycle graphs.

Comment: I think that morally answers my question.

Comment: The other "moral" problem with your question is that we can simply compute the numbers $P_1$ and $P_2$ in polynomial time.

Comment: Yeah technically speaking I want to be in Logspace but since I am talking to mathematicians I figured some amount of difficulty becomes evident with the way I am portraying (there is no known logspace or even non-deterministic logspace (both are conjectured to be same) algorithm to find $P_1$ or $P_2$).

Comment: It's true that you can compute $P_1$ and $P_2$ in polynomial time (polynomial of the size of the input graphs) and then you can make the cycle graph of length $P_1+P_2$. But that cycle graph can be exponentially large (with respect to input size). So I don't think this solution qualifies as "a graph construction in polynomial time", at least if you require an explicit output of the constructed graph.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen there may be other tricks to reduce to polynomial size. The point of the problem is not to compute P1 and P2 ahead of time. I need a blind construction.